# Deriving from Generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Generic class is base class, and a member method uses generic data type, how will you make the method of derived accept integers instead of generic data type?

Comment: If you need your derived class to be specific rather than generic, just set the type constraint when inheriting: `public class MyClass : BaseClass<int>`

Comment: @KooKiz: I think you should make this an answer. It's a simple question, but a valid one, and your comment answers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
public class MyBaseClass<T>
{
    public virtual void MyMethod(T typeT)
    {
      //some important functionality
    }
}

public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass<int>
{
    public override void MyMethod(int typeInt)
    {
        //Do your stuff
        //and if you would like to call base method, use the following-
        base.MyMethod(typevar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It serves the purpose :)